# Loading Bearing Studs issue

Tags: electrical, framing, structural, load-bearing

I have some questions/concerns about my load bearing studs/wall in my basement stairs.
My house is just 3 years old house and no modification done yet to any load bearing wall yet.

You can see the pic in Basement stair Front ( 1st picture), how joists ( just above the stair's landing) are running. Both the Stairs Left/Right side walls are load bearing wall.

And, I found a weird thing with the load bearing studs ( see pic "Stair Right Side - Load bearing Double Studs" or 2nd picture)). The double studs (has cut from top)  are not actually holding the foyer (in main living)  load, rather its just the stud next to it or other studs in the same wall.

How ? please see there is a gap between double plate and double studs in  the picture.

If you look at left side of stair ( see pic 4th picture). the double studs are correctly installed and actually supporting the load from upstairs.

Actually, I have to make door through the Stair right side load bearing wall and I know I have to install a strong header made of 2 2X10 header and 1/2 plywood between 2X10s.
But I have to fix the existing structural issue.

Also I am not sure why electrician ran wire through 3 studs to install a switch box, why not just straight down from double plate hole. I am not seeing any reason why switchbox can't be on other side of the double studs. There is nothing blocking the switch box there.

Any suggestion and advise will be highly appreciated,

[image: "Basement stair Front"]Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][6]][6]
[![enter image description here][6]][6]

Comment: For the location with 3 studs, what is behind the wall? I think the two studs with saw cut notches are not load bearing, but, from the photo, I couldn't figure out why they are there.

Comment: stairs. Look at the 4th picture from the top. its other wall side of the stairs. do you see double joists load there ?

Comment: Yes. But, if those are joists, where they extend to. We see the butts on this side (4th pic), and there are nothing coming out from the other side(3rd pic). I am confused.

Comment: Look at the very first pick, they are going out towards a load bearing ( facing) wall when step down.

Comment: So the stairs are going down from the area where the studs are cut, I don’t see it if they are going down the plate would have sheer force not load to speak of. If the stairs went up and the plate was supporting the stringers then it would be under load but you said they step down. Remember we can’t see what you can only what the pictures show.

Comment: Those two "modified" studs are definitely not supporting any weight at all. Not only are they cut most of the way through, but they don't even attach to the top plate. They're also much older, more weathered wood, and look like they were added after the original construction by someone who used whatever was lying around. The other side of the drywall there is the stairway, so they're not there to support anything (like a TV mount). Is there anything directly _above_ this attempted column, like a column holding up the 2nd floor?

Comment: Here is the vedio link to understand the issue  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QA4MM0kstw                                                                                                                             @freeman, please check the first seconds of the vedio. yes there is a opening just above . thanks !

Comment: There is no 2nd floor. its a ranch house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had inspector come and looked into this issue.

He was also not sure why it was happened like that way.

He suggested to replace those two studs with new 2 studs. those two studs are just a waste right now as those are not attached to the top plate, also one of the stud is pretty old.

thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting back with what the inspector found!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for posting your inspection results! Make sure you click the check mark so others will know this has a resolution.

Comment: “Old stud” that describes a lot of the users on this website.